# Umbraco v5.x learning resources

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

Umbraco has lately made a move from ASP.NET Web forms to ASP.NET MVC 3. I have tried to find good resources which would help me to get started, but since it is so new I am out of luck. I would not like to go through old material prior v4 era since I don't want to confuse myself more than necessary. Umbraco.tv site does not seem to have many v5 videos if any at all.

Are there any tutorials with Umbraco v5 specific information? I have just started to learn Umbraco so any help is needed, but I need to get started as quickly as possible. I am MVC 3 developer so good examples on how to extend Umbraco with own controllers, models, views etc. would help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any experience with MVC and razor, you could start from the [github documentation](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco5Docs/blob/5.0.1/Documentation/index.md). It will later be available on the [official doc channel](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation)

In Umbraco the controller is a surfacecontroller, and is basically only used you need to do more then show some simple content. [How to use](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco5Docs/blob/5.1.0/Documentation/Getting-Started/Creating-a-surface-controller.md)

That is the documentation there are available right now, but the community is working on getting more documentation ready as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I have found some links and will keep posting them here:

http://h4rdboiledegg.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/adventures-with-umbraco-5/

How to use partial macros: http://shazwazza.com/post/Partial-View-macros-in-Umbraco-v5.aspx

Umbrazo Razor cheat sheet: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet